# Angular Trix not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-trix

I have integrated Angular Trix. its working nice with firefox but not working with the chrome and IE
so what should be the problem??
My code is as below :

```
<trix-editor ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" spellcheck="false" class="trix-content" ng-model="prjoectcreate.description" angular-trix trix-initialize="trixInitialize(e, editor);" trix-change="trixChange(e, editor);" trix-selection-change="trixSelectionChange(e, editor);" trix-focus="trixFocus(e, editor);" trix-blur="trixBlur(e, editor);" placeholder="Write something.."></trix-editor>
```

Comment: Can you provide link to Plunkr with your code.Are there any Console errors ?

Comment: I got the solution. i have to write ng-if='true'. which has solved my problem

Comment: works for me. please, make it an answer

Comment: @beardmeaning Thanks. and i have posted it as answer so you can up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. I have to write `ng-if='true'`. which has solved my problem

Comment: Thank you ! I've spent about 3 hour to try to understand why it doesn't work. You save my work day.

Comment: This actually works perfect, it also sorts binding issues with the scope variable when using Angular Trix in an angular-ui modal.