# Angular-trix not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-10, angular-trix

I'm using [Angular-trix](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-trix/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation) rich text editor, It's working fine in all browsers even `IE 11`, but It isn't working in `IE10` or less.

It's continuously showing following error.

> Unable to set property 'trixMutable' of undefined or null reference

**HTML**

```
<trix-editor ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" spellcheck="false" class="trix-content" ng-model="trix" angular-trix trix-initialize="trixInitialize(e, editor);" trix-change="trixChange(e, editor);" trix-selection-change="trixSelectionChange(e, editor);" trix-focus="trixFocus(e, editor);" trix-blur="trixBlur(e, editor);" trix-file-accept="trixFileAccept(e, editor);" trix-attachment-add="trixAttachmentAdd(e, editor);" trix-attachment-remove="trixAttachmentRemove(e, editor);" placeholder="Write something.."></trix-editor>
```

I can't figureout what's going wrong.

I found this *[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216988/angular-trix-not-working-in-all-browsers)*, but unfortunately not working in my case.

**[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSzwlzUmRQoUtZJke2C4?p=preview)**

I posted same issue on [github](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-trix/issues/28), but I got no response.

**Note:** Please open above plunkr in `IE10` or Less.

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: Yes! I have mentioned already.

Comment: **trixMutable** where have you defined this?

Comment: I haven't define this var `trixMutable` anywhere

Comment: then how will your variable is undefined or null reference will come?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hSzwlzUmRQoUtZJke2C4?p=preview

Comment: it is working perfectly

Comment: Could you please open this in `IE10` or Less.?

Comment: seems like it isn't supposed to work, but maybe sort of will if you add enough pollyfills: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/174

Comment: There is no error in IE10 / IE9 for me.

Comment: @lossleader your solution isn't working for me, maybe I'm missing something, can you provide me any working example.

Comment: @lin Is above added Plunker working for you?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey yea it does work with my fix =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your error by changing trix to the latest version `0.10.1`. Once you add [dataset.js](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/dataset.js) it works like a charm in IE. `dataset.js` will avoid the error by adding missing core dependencies in IE.

> Unable to set property 'trixSelection' of undefined or null reference

#### Full fixed code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="trixDemo">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/0.10.1/trix.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <script src="polyfills.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.4.4" data-semver="1.4.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/0.10.1/trix.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-trix.js"></script> 
  <script src="democtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="trixDemoCtrl">
  <trix-editor ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
               spellcheck="false" class="trix-content" 
               ng-model="trix" 
               angular-trix 
               trix-initialize="trixInitialize(e, editor);" 
               trix-change="trixChange(e, editor);" 
               trix-selection-change="trixSelectionChange(e, editor);" 
               trix-focus="trixFocus(e, editor);" 
               trix-blur="trixBlur(e, editor);" 
               trix-file-accept="trixFileAccept(e, editor);" 
               trix-attachment-add="trixAttachmentAdd(e, editor);" 
               trix-attachment-remove="trixAttachmentRemove(e, editor);" 
               placeholder="Write something.."></trix-editor>
</body>
</html>
```

#### >> [Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQgd7yebnC5cHls5MqZ5?p=preview)

If there is nothing special on `trix.js` I would recommend to swtich to [textAngular](http://textangular.com/) which seems to be much more solid. I hope this fix will help you to implement `trix.js` into your application.

Comment: Your solution for `trix.js` is good, but now I'm going to use `textAngular`, it seems much better, I hope this won't give me any error. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

From their Github Repo i came to know that they are not supporting for **IE10** 
but i gave an attempt to make it work :

**Step 1** : Try to update your `trix.js`  to  `0.10.1`

Here is the [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/0.10.1/trix.js) i used

**Step 2** : When you try to run this code in the IE 10 you will get a new Error

> Unable to set property 'trixSelection' of undefined or null reference

So from [trix Issue list](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/174) if you can add the [`dataset` polyfill](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/remy/polyfills/master/dataset.js)

then the following [plunkner](http://plnkr.co/edit/nScV7pvtCDwPaJiLA5aO) will be working in IE10